# merging two SQL Scripts

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been handed the task of merging two scrips so that we can display notes on the results of the first query.
I know this might be a long shot but if someone could help that would be great.

First Query being the bulk of the data which was given to me from an EXCEL query.

```
SELECT hgmprty1.la_rep_cd AS 'Area', 
  hraptvpd.prty_ref, 
  hraptvpd.init_void_dt AS 'Void Date', 
  hraptvpd.void_reas, 
  hgmprty1.let_yn, 
  hgmprty1.void_stat AS 'Property void code', 
  hraptvpd.init_void_cd AS 'Period initial void code', 
  hraptvpd.cur_void_cd AS 'Period current void code', 
  hraptvps.void_cd AS 'phase void code', 
  hraptvps.st_date, 
  hraptvps.end_date, 
  hgmprty2.sh_size_desn, 
  hgmprty1.need_cat, 
  hgmprty3.status, 
  hraptvpd.void_reas, 
  hraptvps.lst_revn, 
  hgmprty1.dwelling, 
  hraptvps.delay_cd_reas
FROM qlfdat.dbo.hgmprty1 hgmprty1, 
  qlfdat.dbo.hgmprty2 hgmprty2, 
  qlfdat.dbo.hgmprty3 hgmprty3, 
  qlfdat.dbo.hraptvpd hraptvpd, 
  qlfdat.dbo.hraptvps hraptvps
WHERE hgmprty1.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
  AND hraptvpd.prty_ref = hgmprty1.prty_id 
  AND hgmprty2.comp_id = hgmprty1.comp_id 
  AND hgmprty2.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
  AND hgmprty2.prty_id = hgmprty1.prty_id 
  AND hgmprty3.comp_id = hgmprty1.comp_id 
  AND hgmprty3.comp_id = hgmprty2.comp_id 
  AND hgmprty3.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
  AND hgmprty3.prty_id = hgmprty1.prty_id 
  AND hgmprty3.prty_id = hgmprty2.prty_id 
  AND hraptvps.comp_id = hgmprty1.comp_id 
  AND hraptvps.comp_id = hgmprty2.comp_id 
  AND hraptvps.comp_id = hgmprty3.comp_id 
  AND hraptvps.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
  AND hraptvps.prty_ref = hraptvpd.prty_ref 
  AND hraptvpd.seq_no = hraptvps.vd_prd 
  AND ((hgmprty1.dwelling='1') 
      AND (hraptvpd.status='3') 
      OR (hgmprty1.dwelling='2') 
      AND (hraptvpd.status='3') 
      OR (hgmprty1.dwelling='4') 
      AND (hraptvpd.status='3'))
ORDER BY hgmprty1.la_rep_cd
```

Second Query was written by someone else but could possibly be done a ot better.

```
select prty_ref,void_cd,a2.void_desr,a2.note, n1.Notes from hraptvps 
  left join 
(SELECT 
note_id, ql_dt, Note1 + data1 + data2 + data3 + data4 + data5 + data6 + data7 + data8 + data9 + data10 + data11 + data12 + data14 AS Notes
FROM         (SELECT    
c1.note_id, c1.ql_dt, LEFT(c1.note_detail, 251) AS Note1, CASE WHEN c2.data1 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c2.data1 END AS data1, 
                                              CASE WHEN c3.data2 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c3.data2 END AS data2, CASE WHEN c4.data3 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c4.data3 END AS data3, 
                                              CASE WHEN c5.data4 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c5.data4 END AS data4, CASE WHEN c6.data5 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c6.data5 END AS data5, 
                                              CASE WHEN c7.data6 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c7.data6 END AS data6, CASE WHEN c8.data7 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c8.data7 END AS data7, 
                                              CASE WHEN c9.data8 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c9.data8 END AS data8, CASE WHEN c10.data9 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c10.data9 END AS data9, 
                                              CASE WHEN c11.data10 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c11.data10 END AS data10, CASE WHEN c12.data11 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c12.data11 END AS data11, 
                                              CASE WHEN c13.data12 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c13.data12 END AS data12, CASE WHEN c14.data13 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c14.data13 END AS data13, 
                                              CASE WHEN c15.data14 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c15.data14 END AS data14
                       FROM          dbo.cmpnote AS c1 LEFT OUTER JOIN

                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data1
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0001)) AS c2 ON c1.note_id = c2.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data2
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_13
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0002)) AS c3 ON c1.note_id = c3.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data3
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_12
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0003)) AS c4 ON c1.note_id = c4.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data4
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_11
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0004)) AS c5 ON c1.note_id = c5.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data5
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_10
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0005)) AS c6 ON c1.note_id = c6.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data6
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_9
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0006)) AS c7 ON c1.note_id = c7.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data7
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_8
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0007)) AS c8 ON c1.note_id = c8.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data8
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_7
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0008)) AS c9 ON c1.note_id = c9.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data9
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_6
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0009)) AS c10 ON c1.note_id = c10.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data10
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_5
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0010)) AS c11 ON c1.note_id = c10.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data11
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_4
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0011)) AS c12 ON c1.note_id = c12.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data12
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_3
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0012)) AS c13 ON c1.note_id = c13.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data13
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_2
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0013)) AS c14 ON c1.note_id = c14.note_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data14
                                                    FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_1
                                                    WHERE      (segm = 0014)) AS c15 ON c1.note_id = c15.note_id) as n1) as n1



  on a2.note=n1.note_id

  where  n1.notes is not null
```

If somesome could either get both queries to work as one or help me re-write it that would be great. Ive been struggling for a good week.

Comment: merge them how, exactly? both queries are massive and at least the first one is using implicit joins which are outdated by a good 25 years (probably closer to 30 now) - and they don't seem to return the same data so a union is out of the question. Anyway this is way too broad as it is now.

Comment: They can join by prty_ref, but every time I try to join it I get an ambiguous error on the prty_ref coloumn

Comment: what rdbms are you using? Is it SQL Server or sybase? what version? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant product and version tags, and also your join attempts and exact error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can give us some Querys to generate some data and tables I can debug this further. 
Try to comment out most of the stuff not directly necessary for the relation between the 2 querys.

```
            Select * from (

                            SELECT hgmprty1.la_rep_cd AS 'Area', 
                              hraptvpd.prty_ref as 'prty_ref', 
                              hraptvpd.init_void_dt AS 'Void Date', 
                              hraptvpd.void_reas as 'void_reas', 
                              hgmprty1.let_yn as 'let_yn', 
                              hgmprty1.void_stat AS 'Property void code', 
                              hraptvpd.init_void_cd AS 'Period initial void code', 
                              hraptvpd.cur_void_cd AS 'Period current void code', 
                              hraptvps.void_cd AS 'phase void code'
                              --, 
                              --hraptvps.st_date, 
                              --hraptvps.end_date, 
                              --hgmprty2.sh_size_desn, 
                              --hgmprty1.need_cat, 
                              --hgmprty3.status, 
                              --hraptvpd.void_reas, 
                              --hraptvps.lst_revn, 
                              --hgmprty1.dwelling, 
                              --hraptvps.delay_cd_reas
                            FROM qlfdat.dbo.hgmprty1 hgmprty1, 
                              qlfdat.dbo.hgmprty2 hgmprty2, 
                              qlfdat.dbo.hgmprty3 hgmprty3, 
                              qlfdat.dbo.hraptvpd hraptvpd, 
                              qlfdat.dbo.hraptvps hraptvps
                            WHERE hgmprty1.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
                              AND hraptvpd.prty_ref = hgmprty1.prty_id 
                              AND hgmprty2.comp_id = hgmprty1.comp_id 
                              AND hgmprty2.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
                              AND hgmprty2.prty_id = hgmprty1.prty_id 
                              AND hgmprty3.comp_id = hgmprty1.comp_id 
                              AND hgmprty3.comp_id = hgmprty2.comp_id 
                              AND hgmprty3.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
                              AND hgmprty3.prty_id = hgmprty1.prty_id 
                              AND hgmprty3.prty_id = hgmprty2.prty_id 
                              AND hraptvps.comp_id = hgmprty1.comp_id 
                              AND hraptvps.comp_id = hgmprty2.comp_id 
                              AND hraptvps.comp_id = hgmprty3.comp_id 
                              AND hraptvps.comp_id = hraptvpd.comp_id 
                              AND hraptvps.prty_ref = hraptvpd.prty_ref 
                              AND hraptvpd.seq_no = hraptvps.vd_prd 
                              AND ((hgmprty1.dwelling='1') 
                                  AND (hraptvpd.status='3') 
                                  OR (hgmprty1.dwelling='2') 
                                  AND (hraptvpd.status='3') 
                                  OR (hgmprty1.dwelling='4') 
                                  AND (hraptvpd.status='3'))
                            ORDER BY hgmprty1.la_rep_cd
                        )Qry1

            LEFT JOIN 
                            (
                            select a2.prty_ref as 'prty_ref', --,a2.void_cd ,  a2.void_desr,a2.note, 
                            n1.Notes 
                            from hraptvps a2
                              left join 
                                (SELECT 
                                note_id, ql_dt, Note1 + data1 + data2 + data3 + data4 + data5 + data6 + data7 + data8 + data9 + data10 + data11 + data12 + data14 AS Notes
                                FROM         (SELECT    
                                                    c1.note_id, c1.ql_dt, LEFT(c1.note_detail, 251) AS Note1, CASE WHEN c2.data1 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c2.data1 END AS data1, 
                                                                    CASE WHEN c3.data2 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c3.data2 END AS data2, CASE WHEN c4.data3 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c4.data3 END AS data3, 
                                                                    CASE WHEN c5.data4 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c5.data4 END AS data4, CASE WHEN c6.data5 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c6.data5 END AS data5, 
                                                                    CASE WHEN c7.data6 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c7.data6 END AS data6, CASE WHEN c8.data7 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c8.data7 END AS data7, 
                                                                    CASE WHEN c9.data8 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c9.data8 END AS data8, CASE WHEN c10.data9 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c10.data9 END AS data9, 
                                                                    CASE WHEN c11.data10 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c11.data10 END AS data10, CASE WHEN c12.data11 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c12.data11 END AS data11, 
                                                                    CASE WHEN c13.data12 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c13.data12 END AS data12, CASE WHEN c14.data13 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c14.data13 END AS data13, 
                                                                    CASE WHEN c15.data14 IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE c15.data14 END AS data14
                                                    FROM          dbo.cmpnote AS c1 

                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN

                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data1
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0001)
                                                ) AS c2 ON c1.note_id = c2.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data2
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_13
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0002)) AS c3 ON c1.note_id = c3.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data3
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_12
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0003)) AS c4 ON c1.note_id = c4.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data4
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_11
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0004)) AS c5 ON c1.note_id = c5.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data5
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_10
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0005)) AS c6 ON c1.note_id = c6.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data6
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_9
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0006)) AS c7 ON c1.note_id = c7.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data7
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_8
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0007)) AS c8 ON c1.note_id = c8.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data8
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_7
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0008)) AS c9 ON c1.note_id = c9.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data9
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_6
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0009)) AS c10 ON c1.note_id = c10.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data10
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_5
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0010)) AS c11 ON c1.note_id = c10.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data11
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_4
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0011)) AS c12 ON c1.note_id = c12.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data12
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_3
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0012)) AS c13 ON c1.note_id = c13.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data13
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_2
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0013)) AS c14 ON c1.note_id = c14.note_id 
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                (SELECT     note_id, segm, LEFT(data, 251) AS Data14
                                                FROM          dbo.ocmpnote AS ocmpnote_1
                                                WHERE      (segm = 0014)) AS c15 ON c1.note_id = c15.note_id
                                            ) 

                                    as n1) as n1 on a2.Note =n1.note_id

                                      where  n1.notes is not null
                            )  Qry2 on Qry1.prty_ref = Qry2.prty_ref
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up creating a temp table with the second script and the first script I re wrote this with correct joins and it seems to work now.